# Adding all the numbers in a Range, including the number

Tags: python

I was trying to create a function that added up the range of a number, including the number.

So when I input 5, I should receive 15.

Why is this function not working?

```
def sum_nums(number):
    start = 0 
    for index in range(0,len(number)):
        start += index
    return start 

print sum_nums(5)
```

Comment: Try replacing `len(number)` with `number`.

Comment: Why are you taking the `len` of the number instead of just using it for the `range`?

Comment: Also: this code should be giving you an error message. Please always include any errors you're getting in the question.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your response. The problem is if I replace it with "number" instead of "len(number), then it will only return the addition up to the number before 5. So in this instance the answer of sum_nums(5)  ----> 10 and I want it to include 5 so the answer will be 15

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/bg/intro_class/extra_lists/dict_practice.py", line 22, in <module>
    print sum_nums(5)
  File "/Users/bg/intro_class/extra_lists/dict_practice.py", line 18, in sum_nums
    for index in range(0,len(number)):
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()

Comment: While I realize this is most likely a programming exercise (rather than a problem you really need to solve for some other reason), you might be interested to know that there's a closed form solution (e.g. a solution with no loops). The sum of the integers up to and including `number` is `number * (number + 1) // 2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be done with a 1 liner but i'll help you out with a solution in the format that you're attempting.

```
def sum_nums(number):
    total = 0
    for i in range(number + 1):
        total += i
    print total
```

Input `5`

Output `15`

Also, some clarification as per your error message. `len` is to be used for strings. An integer does not have a length. By simply passing it to the `range` function it will try all of the numbers (if you don't specify a starting number) from 1 up to that number, but not including it. That's why we do `range(number + 1)` to include the target number.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 2):

This question would be amiss if someone didn't mention that `sum(range(n))` is always `n*(n-1)/2`. If you wish to do this inclusive of the value `n`, the expressions are `sum(range(n+1))` and `n*(n+1)/2`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the python built in 'reduce' like below. Also what you want can be achieved when you start from 1 and iterate till 6.

```
reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, range(1, 6))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in a one liner with:

```
def sum_range_inclusive(number):
    return sum(range(number + 1))
```

To break this down:

```
# assume number is 5 for now
number = 5    

# exclusive, doesn't include the number
range(number)
# returns [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

# inclusive, includes the number
range(number + 1)
# returns [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

# sum of inclusive range
sum([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
# returns 15
```

Comment: Nice! Didn't realize that you could just `sum` a range like that!

Comment: Yeah, range returns a `list()` and `sum()` can sum any iterable containing numbers including lists, tuples, sets, etc.

Comment: good to know, thanks! Except `range` does not return a `list` afaik; at least not in Python 3. That is why I added the `list` call in my answer (which I deleted because yours is better); I thought that was necessary before.

Comment: Python 2 returns a list, Python 3 returns an immutable `range` type. A `range` is similar to a tuple and still an iterable sequence type, so `sum()` should still work.

Comment: it does still work in Python 3 since, as you said, it is an iterable. Yeah, I was testing in a Python 3 interpreter on my phone, but didn't test 2. Very informative, thanks again!